# Merge csv files with same header: passing multiple files to awk with xargs

Tags: csv, awk, xargs

I need to merge together all csv files of a directory that have the same header (1st line). Let's say we have:

file a.txt:

```
head1,head2,head3
1,2,"abc"
8,42,"def"
```

file b.txt:

```
head4,head2
"aa",2
```

file c.txt:

```
head1,head2,head3
12,2,"z"
15,2,"z"
```

If I want all files with header "head1,head2,head3", then it should merge files a and c and produce:

```
awk 'FNR==1 && NR!=1{next;}{print}' a.txt c.txt 
head1,head2,head3
1,2,"abc"
8,42,"def"
12,2,"z"
15,2,"z"
```

---

Now I can, for a given header, detect the files to merge automatically, but I can't pass the resulting list to awk. I am using the following command:

```
head -n1 -v * | grep -B1 "head1,head2,head3" | awk "/==>/{ print \$2 }" | xargs -l -0 awk 'FNR==1 && NR!=1{next;}{print}'
awk: fatal: cannot open file `a.txt
c.txt
' for reading (No such file or directory)
```

where `head` lists the file names and first lines, `grep` keeps only the headers that are matching (and associated filenames on the preceding lines with -B1), and the first call to `awk` keeps only the file names, one per line.
I tried as well (adding `tr '\n' ' '`):

```
head -n1 -v * | grep -B1 "head1,head2,head3" | awk "/==>/{ print \$2 }" | tr '\n' ' ' | xargs -l -0 awk 'FNR==1 && NR!=1{next;}{print}'                       
awk: fatal: cannot open file `a.txt c.txt ' for reading (No such file or directory)
```

I eventually tried the following (using `tr '\n' '\0'` instead):

```
head -n1 -v * | grep -B1 "head1,head2,head3" | awk "/==>/{ print \$2 }" | tr '\n' '\0' | xargs -l -0 awk 'FNR==1 && NR!=1{next;}{print}'                            
head1,head2,head3
1,2,"abc"
8,42,"def"
head1,head2,head3
12,2,"z"
15,2,"z"
```

(although I'm not sure to understand exactly how `\0` is interpreted), at least this command works but it looks like each file is processed separately by awk, as the header is printed two times.

What am I missing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Does this help?

```
$ awk -v h='head1,head2,head3' 'BEGIN{print h} FNR==1{f=$0==h?1:0; next} f' *.txt
head1,head2,head3
1,2,"abc"
8,42,"def"
12,2,"z"
15,2,"z"
```

- `-v h='head1,head2,head3'` save the header line to check in a variable `h`
- `BEGIN{print h}` print the header (assumes there'll be at least one file that matches)
- `FNR==1{f=$0==h?1:0; next}` set/clear flag based on first line of file matching contents of `h`
- `f` print if flag is set
- `*.txt` list of files to merge

With GNU awk, you can skip unnecessarily reading files that don't match by using `FNR==1{if($0!=h) nextfile; next} 1`

Comment: Perfect, thank you! I thought there might be an easier solution like that, but I was worried that it would be more expensive as it would require to compare all lines. Skipping files with non-matching headers looks like a nice solution to me.